# Size of intersection between sets

Tags: probability

Let sets $A_i, i\in [1,\ldots,k]$, be sets of $O(\sqrt{n})$ **arbitrarily** chosen numbers without repetitions in range $[1,\ldots,n]$. Consider a set $B$ with **randomly** chosen $O(\sqrt{n})$ distinct numbers in range $[1\ldots,n]$.
Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^{k}|A_i \cap B|$. I want to show that for $k=O(\sqrt{n})$:
$$X = O(\sqrt{n})$$
with exponential high probability.

I considered the following simple approach but not sure if it correct.

Let $D_j^i$ be the indicator r.v. indicating that the number at position $j$ in $B$ appears in $A_i$. So, $\Pr(D_i=1)=\frac{O(\sqrt{n})}{n}=O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$.

Now, assuming that $D_j^i$ are independent, we have that:
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^{O(\log n)}\sum_{j=1}^{O(\log n)}D_j^i$$
which is a sum of $O(n)$ independent Poisson trials for which we have simple Chernoff bound (for $\delta>2e-1$):
$$\Pr(X>(1+\delta)E[X])\le 2^{-\delta E[X]}$$
Since $E[X]=n E[D_j^i]=nO(1/\sqrt{n})=O(\sqrt{n})$ we get for $\delta=2e$:
$$\Pr(X>(1+2e)O(\sqrt{n}))\le 2^{-2e O(\sqrt{n})}.$$

The problem with this approach is that $D_j^i$ are dependent (for example if all sets $A_i$ are the same). Can anybody suggest another approach to show that $X=O(\sqrt{n})$ or justify the assumption of $D_j^i$ independence? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it will not be possible to get a bound like the one you give above.

For example, let $n':=\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$, and consider the case where $k=n'$, all $A_i$s are the same and equal $\{1,\dots,n'\}$, and $B$ contains $n'$ randomly chosen distinct elements of $\{1,\dots,n\}$.  In this case $X=n' Y$ where $Y$ has a hypergeometric distribution (it equals the number of successes when drawing $n'$ cards out of a deck of $n$, $n'$ of which are successes.)  For small $\ell$ and large $n$, the probability that $Y$ equals $\ell$ will be well-approximated by the probability that a Poisson random variable with parameter $1$ equals $\ell$, giving in this case
$$
{\Bbb P}(X=\ell\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)=\frac1{\ell!e}(1+O(\frac{\ell^2+1}{\sqrt{n}})).$$

Comment: OK, I understand. Thanks David!